# For Each Loop in Google Sheets? VBA For Example

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

In Picture 1, the green cell means a column with a formula. The only columns I want to sum in row 13 are the the columns that don't have formulas in them, and columns that = "Upfront Costs" and merged with row 10. So in Picture 1, the answer would be $97(the sum of (A13:F13) - D13).

Picture 1
[image]

VBA for Picture 1 Example

```
Sub test()
 Dim cl As Object, count As Double
    For Each cl In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("10:10")
        If cl.MergeCells Then
            If cl.Offset(3, 0).HasFormula = False And cl.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Upfront Costs" Then
                count = count + cl.Offset(3, 0).Value
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox count
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

In Picture 2, If "Upfront Costs" was merged from "B10:L10" the answer would be $289 
(the sum of (B13:L13) - D13).

Picture 2
[image: PICTURE 2]

In Picture 3 example, if "Upfront Costs" was merged from "L10:N10" the answer would be $122 (sum of L13:N13")

Picture 3
[image]

Comment: Review the documentation. Share the errors you get and your attempts to understand the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function fnct_sum() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var cl , count=0 ;
    var yourRange = sheet.getRange("10:10");
    for (var i = 1; i < yourRange.getNumColumns()+1; i++)
    {
        cl=yourRange.getCell(1, i);
        if (cl.isPartOfMerge())
        {
            Logger.log(cl.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1, 1).getValue());
            if (cl.offset(3, 0).getFormula()=="" && cl.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1, 1).getValue()=='Upfront Costs') 
            {
               count = count + cl.offset(3, 0).getValue();
            }

            else 
            {
               Logger.log (count);
               //break;
            }   
       }
    }
    Logger.log (count);
};
```

Comment: I get 142 for range a10:G10 merged and in D13=sum(A13:C13) and other cell constant. And you must ensure that in D13 is formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Summing Cells below a merged range**

This function assumes that there are no other merge ranges intersecting this row and the the string "Upfront Costs" is always left most cell of the merged range which it has to be in order to be seen.  We could have also done this with background coloring.

```
function runTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(10,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  if(rg.getMergedRanges()[0].getValue()=="Upfront Costs") {
    var mrg=rg.getMergedRanges()[0];
    var vA=sh.getRange(13,mrg.getColumn(),1,mrg.getWidth()).getDisplayValues()[0];
    var fA=sh.getRange(13,mrg.getColumn(),1,mrg.getWidth()).getFormulas()[0];
    var sum=0;
    vA.forEach(function(e,i){if(!fA[i]){sum+=Number(e);}})
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Range: ' + mrg.getA1Notation() + ' Sum: ' + sum);
    return sum;
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Does not meet criteria');
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a couple typos.  Please try it again

Comment: Is there a way to offset from (e)? I am still getting a sum of all the numbers and not just the ones that are under the merged cell "Upfront Costs"

Comment: In your question you say `I want to sum the cells in row 13`. Is that not true?

Comment: I tested this and it's working on my sheet.  It's currently summing everything on row thirteen.

Comment: I want to sum the cells in row 13 ONLY if row 10 is merged and says "Upfront Costs" The answer in this example should be $117. It should only be calculating columns "A:F"

Comment: I just made a small change.  Try it again.

Comment: Upfront Costs can change, So I merged Upfront Costs from A:L and I am still getting 117. I still need to sum all of them in case Upfront Costs changes.

Comment: I think I'm understanding that you want to sum the cells in row 13 whose column intersect the merge range.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the confusion. I want to sum row 13 values ONLY if row 10 is merged with the value "Upfront Costs". This can change many times.

Comment: Only if row 10 is merged and a value of "Upfront Costs" and only the cells that are in the columns that are part of that merge.  Is that correct?

Comment: If "Upfront Costs" was merged across "A10:M10" the answer should be 369. If it was merged across "A10:H10" the answer should be 167.

Comment: I'm trying to get a yes or no answer.

Comment: Oh an so the  merge wont always started in row one.

Comment: Rewrite the question. I'll get back with you later.

Comment: Yes to your question. I will re-write it sorry for the confusion.

Comment: hope this better explains it, thank you for the help so far!

Comment: thanks for the edit! I am getting a sum on NaN for reason.

Comment: I changed vA.forEach(function(e,i){if(!fA[i]){sum+=Number(e);}}) to vA.forEach(function(e,i){if(!fA[i]){sum+=Number(i);}}) and now i am getting 36 as a sum with Picture 1 Example